# My function is returning a Promise and I never told the function to return a Promise

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I'm making a module for my database, but I dont know why my function is returning a Promise, heres the code:

```js
async function GetGuildData(guildID) {
    if(await guildDataModel.exists({ guildID: guildID })) {
        guildDataModel.findOne({ guildID: guildID }).then(document => {
            return document;
        }).catch(error => console.error("[ERROR] An error ocurred while I was trying to get guild data:\n\n".red, error));
    } else {
        return console.error("[ERROR] The guild doesn't exist".red)
    };
};
```

Please help, I dont know why is this ocurring:

- **MongoDB - Mongoose**

Comment: It should return `document`, in the line: `return document;`

Comment: You defined your function as async function. async function always returns a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like everyone has said async functions always return promises,

also this would not work:

```js
.then(document => {
    return document;
});
```

It does essentially nothing. You would need to return the promise in the if statement, as so:

```js
if(await guildDataModel.exists({ guildID: guildID })) {
    return guildDataModel.findOne({ guildID: guildID });
}
```

and then in some other section

```js
const data = await GetGuildData(guildID).catch(err => {});
```

Comment: Beware that top level await is in Stage 3 (https://tc39.es/proposal-top-level-await/), implemented in V8. Not all browsers, the behavior is guaranteed.

Comment: I am aware, I was not using top level await, I was just showing the if statement block he had which was inside of an async function. As for the `const data = ...`  I assumed OP would know that.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the implicit gotchas ES6 has brought.. Check out MDN docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Async functions return a `Promise`

If what you return is not already a promise, it wrapped with a `Promise`:

`Promise.resolve(whatever)`

If you don't want to use then, you might do something like:

```
 !async function(){

     //define GetGuildData
     let data = await GetGuildData(whatever);
     //do something with data

    }();
```

Comment: How can I do to make the function return the `document`?

Comment: Call this function within another async function and use await. Or get used to using 'then'.

Comment: I didn't understand correctly... You mean remove the `async` in the function and add the `async` when calling the function?

Comment: @Sandessat since your function depends on other promises, your function will need to return a promise too if it's going to be useful. You cannot get around this.

Comment: @Sandessat, check my answer, you have some studying to do..

Comment: So, when I call the function, do I need to call it like this?

Comment: ```js
GetGuildData(message.guild.id).then(guildData => {
```

Comment: That's one way yes, the other is using await.